# Can't connect to mysql inside docker on osx

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, connection, freeze

Lately, my docker container is refusing connections.  It has worked well in the past, this issue is new and has no explanation so far.

Stopping and restarting the container has no effect.
Stopping and restarting Docker for Desktop for Mac has no effect.

I can resolve it only by rebooting my OSX Laptop.  (macOS Mojave v 10.14.5)
Then it will work for a while, and then it starts blocking connection attempts again

I can exec into the container, e.g.

```
docker exec -it db /bin/bash
```

From within the container I can access mysql no problem.

I've tried enabling the general log in mysql to try to debug it:
  It shows no activity...

My laptop has plenty of free disk space (188GB free)

All this worked well for the last 6 months, but just suddenly started blocking connections after working briefly in the last week or so....

Thank you for any clues or ideas

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.7

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y procps
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y debianutils
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y iputils-ping
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y vim
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y less
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y man
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y sudo

WORKDIR .

COPY ./my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf

#CMD ["mysqld", "--general_log=1", "--log-raw", "--log-error"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

my docker-compose file:

(MYSQL_DATA_FOLDER is an environment variable that is set to a valid path

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  database:
    image: database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    volumes:
      - mydatavolume:${MYSQL_DATA_FOLDER}
    build:
      context: .

volumes:
  mydatavolume:

networks:
  default:
    name: dev_network
    driver: bridge
```

How I start it up:

```
docker-compose build; 
docker-compose run --service-ports --volume=$MYSQL_DATA_FOLDER:/var/lib/mysql --name db --rm database
```

How I usually connect (via mysql client in osx terminal)

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root
```

I've also tried variations using 127.0.0.1 and also the IP address revealed by docker inspect

My my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

tried adding:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

to the above... doesn't help

users table

```
mysql> SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| host      | user          |
+-----------+---------------+
| %         | root          |
| %         | some_user     |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
+-----------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

New information:

I have removed the data volume and let it create a new one.  Now the problem is gone - so, it seems to be a MySQL issue and not a Docker issue.  I would still like to know how to debug this kind of MySQL issue when it occurs..

Comment: Did you tried running similar steps on some different machine other than your laptop. Have you verified that.

Comment: The my.cnf could be useful as well so we can see if there is any custom configuration that might cause this issue

Comment: my.cnf is there....

Comment: I don't have access to other machines...

Comment: What is the error that you get? Any firewall software that you use

Comment: Connections just hang indefinitely.   Eventually my debugger times out waiting.  Mysql client just hangs forever and ever.    Not running any firewall software I'm aware of - besides, it works for a while after a reboot, then starts blocking connections again.

Comment: try using : 
`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`

Comment: Maybe you should run service-port :
`docker-compose run --service-ports db`

Comment: If you read through the whole question - you'll see that I already have been doing that

Answer (score 2):

May be there is a security restriction that is preventing connections from **root** user. Can you try creating a local user with necessary privileges as follows.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'some_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'some_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Restart the container and try connecting using the local user.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u some_user --protocol=TCP -P 3306 -p
```

Comment: Ok, it just hung again and logging as non-root makes no difference.  I wish I knew a way to debug this one